# Populate checkbox with data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have a dropdown of car make and I want to populate checkbox with car models that depends onto the selected car make

Controller

```
public JsonResult carmodelList(int Id)
{
    var carmodel = from s in db.CarModel where s.Make_id == Id select s;
    return Json(new SelectList(carmodel.ToArray(), "Model_id", "ModelName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public IList<CarModel> Getmodel(int Model_id)
{
    return db.CarModel.Where(m => m.Model_id == Model_id).ToList();
}

public JsonResult LoadClassesBymake_id(string MakeName)
{
    var carmodelList = this.Getmodel(Convert.ToInt32(MakeName));
    var carmodelData = carmodelList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = m.ModelName,
        Value = m.Make_id.ToString(),
    });
    return Json(carmodelData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("jeffscading", "Car", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>Car Make Types</div>
    @Html.DropDownList("CarMake", ViewBag.Make_id as SelectList, "Select a Make", new { id = "CarMake" })
    <div >CarModel Assigned to the CarMake</div>
    <select id="CarModel" name="CarModel"></select><br />
    <input type="submit" value="SAVE" />
}

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script type="text/jscript">
    $(function () {
        $('#CarMake').change(function () {
            $.getJSON('/Car/carmodelList/' + $('#CarMake').val(), function (data) {
                var items = '<option>Select a members</option>';
                $.each(data, function (i, carmodel) {
                    items += "<option value='" + carmodel.Value + "'>" + carmodel.Text + "</option>";
                });
                $('#CarModel').html(items);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You're going to need to add more. Where are you stuck? Is something not working as you would expect?

Comment: i'm able to show car models if its a dropdown, I was trying to change that dropdown to a checkbox

Comment: You mean a list of checkboxes?

Comment: yes list of checkboxes that belongs to the selected car make

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of checkboxes, one option is [MvcCheckboxList](http://mvccbl.com/).

Another option is a foreach loop, looping through all the options, outputting a checkbox.